# Create an edgelist from a dict object

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dict object:

```
{0: array([1, 2, 3]), 1: array([4,5,6])}
```

Desired output is an edge list:

```
[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6]
```

How can I do this in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use plain `list-comprehension`:

```
import numpy as np
d = {0: np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1: np.array([4,5,6])}

[[key, v] for key, vals in d.items() for v in vals.tolist()]
# [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6]]
```

If you need an array:

```
np.array([[key, v] for key, vals in d.items() for v in vals.tolist()])
```